# How to do Snyk code test in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, devops, snyk, sast, devsecops

I am helping our DevOps team integrate Snyk into the Jenkins pipelines for SAST. By default, it seems like this Snyk plugin is doing `snyk test` (which does open-source dependency scans) and appends the additional arguments provided with it. I identified this behavior by checking the console log where the actual command ran was displayed. We actually want it to do the source code scan `snyk code`.

The command I observed in the console log is this: `<jenkins tools installation path>/snyk-linux test --json --severity-threshold=high --file=<path>/package.json`; The `snyk-linux test` part seems to be predefined.

Can someone please help me regarding this?

Answer (score 4):

As you have correctly observed, the Snyk Security Jenkins plugin only offers access to the Snyk CLI `snyk test` command and nothing else.

Currently, the only way to do this is to talk with the Snyk CLI directly.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    environment {
        SNYK_HOME = tool name: 'Snyk'
    }

    stages {
        
        stage('Snyk Code') {
            steps {
                sh "${SNYK_HOME}/snyk-linux code test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you also need to expose the token in an environment variable.

Comment: This answer is correct. @iamahecker Please accept if you're ok with it.

Answer (score 0):

Running Snyk CLI directly is indeed the only way at the moment.

However, if any code vulnerabilities are detected, the CLI command seems to be failing the build, with a non-zero exit code most certainly.

The Snyk vendor should support this in a future version of the Snyk Jenkins Plugin.

Another alternative, is the Snyk Maven Plugin but only for Maven projects and IMHO it is not as elegant as the Jenkins Plugin.